# Double Push Notification Icon

Tags: android, push-notification, icons

I have designed my android push notification icon according to the guidelines for sdk >= lollipop.
The notification status icon on top of my mobile phone is works perfect ... which is set as smallicon
I have assigned color icon as largeicon to be shown with the message. But this lageicon shows the small icon along with it at the right hand bottom corner as shown in the attachment ( image only for ref) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miVXm.png)
How do I remove this small icon ???
Thanks for help
Sohan kumar

Answer (score 2):

make the small icon invisible after building the notification. below code will help you:

```
int smallIconId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("right_icon", "id", android.R.class.getPackage().getName());
            if (smallIconId != 0) {
                notification.contentView.setViewVisibility(smallIconId, View.INVISIBLE);
                notification.bigContentView.setViewVisibility(smallIconId, View.INVISIBLE);
            }
```

Comment: Hi Anjali ... its not working... also sometimes the large icon shows up and sometimes just a grey circle